# vtk data format error

Tags: vtk

I'm trying to visualize some data I have stored on a regular grid using VTK (drawing a colored isosurface).  I wrote some code to dump the data in the vtk legacy format which works for low resolution versions of the data.  I can extract and view the expected isosurface with ParaView or the VTK library.  When I increase the resolution by a factor of 10 in each dimension (nx goes from about 100 to 1000, same with ny, nz), paraview and a viewer I wrote using the VTK library are incorrect.  They look like a set of slightly off-axis sheets instead of a single "blob".  I know from other tests that the data itself is correct.

Is there something wrong with my legacy vtk format dumping code below?  I don't understand what the lookup table does, but it seems to work fine for the low resolution case.

```
std::ofstream out(filename);

out << "# vtk DataFile Version 3.0" << std::endl;
out << "Signed distance/biharmonic visualizer" << std::endl;
out << "ASCII" << std::endl;
out << "DATASET STRUCTURED_POINTS" << std::endl;
out << "DIMENSIONS " << nx << " " << ny << " " << nz << std::endl;
out << "ORIGIN 0 0 0" << std::endl;
out << "SPACING " << h << " " << h << " " << h << std::endl;
out << "POINT_DATA " << nx*ny*nz << std::endl;
out << "SCALARS signedDistance double" << std::endl;
out << "LOOKUP_TABLE default" << std::endl;
for(size_t i = 0; i < nx; ++i)
  for(size_t j = 0; j < ny; ++j)
    for(size_t k = 0; k < nz; ++k)
      out << tempPhi(i,j,k) << std::endl;
out << "SCALARS biharmonic double" << std::endl;
out << "LOOKUP_TABLE default" << std::endl;
for(size_t i = 0; i < nx; ++i)
  for(size_t j = 0; j < ny; ++j)
    for(size_t k = 0; k < nz; ++k)
      out << biharmonic(i,j,k) << std::endl;
out.close();
```

Comment: Not sure what is wrong here - this would appear to output a file which matches the VTK file format specification (although I don't really know C++). Do the readers work if only one scalar variable is outputted (at the higher resolution)?. Could you post an example VTK file somewhere so we could see the actual output?

Comment: Same problem, even when just outputting the first field.  full sample data file is here:  http://www.cs.utah.edu/~benjones/gridDump000008.vtk.  

Also, here's a picture of what the iso surface is vs what it should be:  http://www.cs.utah.edu/~benjones/isoFail.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the VTK file you provide there are a number of occurrences of `1.79769e+308`. To actually 'see' your data I had to replace these with zeros. Having done this and looked at your data file in [VisIt](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/visit/) I would guess that your method of writing the point data is incorrect (your three nested for loops - which flatten the data from 3D to a 1D list).

I would suggest that you you write some small test data sets with your VTK writer and also with [this](http://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=VisItWriterLib) simple C code, which is supplied with VisIt to write legacy VTK files. Make sure that the data sets written with both methods agree exactly (note that VisItWriterLib.c writes version 2 VTK file formats, whereas you use version 3 - this shouldn't cause a problem however).

**Edit:** As discussed in the comments, the problem was the ordering of the nested for loops which were used to output the point data and flatten it from 3D to a 1D list. The code

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < nx; ++i)
  for(size_t j = 0; j < ny; ++j)
    for(size_t k = 0; k < nz; ++k)
      out << tempPhi(i,j,k) << std::endl;
```

should in fact read

```
for(size_t k = 0; k < nz; ++k)
  for(size_t j = 0; j < ny; ++j)
    for(size_t i = 0; i < nx; ++i)
      out << tempPhi(i,j,k) << std::endl;
```

i.e. the data should be written in **column** major order, not row major. This is a point in which the VTK file formats document is lacking.

Comment: Since I only care about the 0 isosurface, why would those large value matter?  Do you have any idea why the small datasets give me useful results, but not the large ones?  It seems to me that if it was a flattening issue, it would show up at any resolution.

Comment: @BenJones The removal of the large values was just to view the data and not have it dominated by those values. From this it seems that the data is being read in 'wrong' - as in not in the format expected of a VTK file. Therefore, I suggest you write some test data with your method and with a method which we know works, like `VisItWriterLib.c`. This is an easy way to check for the correct format of your output file.

Comment: @BenJones The fact that your data seems ok at low resolution but not at high resolution suggests to me that your VTK writer routine is outputting incorrectly formatted data at all resolutions. Its just happens to seem ok at low resolution. I'm just guessing here by try swapping the order of your nested loops (swap the `i` and `k` indices) and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Swapping the i and k loops did it.  I'm still amazed it was working at low resolution.  Does the format spec say what ordering the points should be given in somewhere?  I just assumed it would be row major, but it looks like it expected column major.

Comment: @BenJones The file formats document (www.vtk.org/VTK/img/file-formats.pdf) could be a lot better! I can't see anywhere what the correct point ordering should be is mentioned (at least I can't find it). This is why it is always useful, if you can, to compare with something you know works. I'm glad you've got it working.