# Writing a VTK ASCII Legacy File to draw contours in VisIt

Tags: c, vtk, contour

I'm trying to write a legacy `.vtk` file to be read into VisIt using C. Unfortunately my installed VisIt program refuses to render the VTK file that I have writing, reading: 'local host failed'

Below is the code used to read data from one file and convert it to a legacy VTK file. I use the macros `XPIX`, `YPIX`, and `ZPIX` to describe the dimensions of a pixel grid. Each pixel contains a scalar density value. I have listed the pixels in a 'grid-file' using row-major ordering: i.e.

```
int list_index(x,y,z) = YPIX * ZPIX * x + ZPIX * y + z;
```

Every entry in this pixel list is read into an array called `grid[]` of type double, and written to `outfile` beneath the legacy VTK header data:

```
/*Write vtk header */                                                           
fprintf(outfile,"# vtk DataFile Version 3.0\n");                                
fprintf(outfile,"Galaxy density grid\nASCII\nDATASET STRUCTURED_POINTS\n");     
fprintf(outfile,"DIMENSIONS %d %d %d \n", (XPIX+1), (YPIX+1), (ZPIX+1));        
fprintf(outfile,"ORIGIN 0 0 0\n");                                              
fprintf(outfile,"SPACING 1 1 1\n");//or ASPECT_RATIO                            
fprintf(outfile,"CELL_DATA %d\n", totalpix);                                    
fprintf(outfile,"SCALARS cell_density float 1\n");                              
fprintf(outfile, "LOOKUP_TABLE default\n");                                     

/*Create Memory Space to store Pixel Grid*/                                     
double *grid;                                                                   
grid = malloc(XPIX * YPIX * ZPIX * sizeof(double));                             
if (grid == NULL ){                                                             
  fprintf(stderr, "Pixel grid of type double failed to initialize\n");          
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                           
}                                                                               
fprintf(stderr,"Pixel grid has been initialized.\n Now reading infile\n");      

/*Read infile contents into double grid[], using Row-Major Indexing*/           
double rho;                                                                     
char newline;                                                                   
int i, j, k;                                                                    
for(i = 0; i < XPIX; i++){                                                      
  for(j = 0; j < YPIX; j++){                                                    
    for(k = 0; k < ZPIX; k++){                                                  
      fscanf(infile, "%lf", &rho);                                              
      grid[getindex(i,j,k)] = rho;                                              
    }                                                                           
  }                                                                             
  fprintf(stderr,"%d\n", i);                                                    
}                                                                               
fprintf(stderr,"Finished reading\n");                                           

#if !DEBUG                                                                      
/*Write out grid contents in Row major order*/                                  
fprintf(stderr,"Now writing vtk file");                                         
for(i = 0; i < XPIX; i++){                                                      
  for(j = 0; j < YPIX; j++){                                                    
    for(k = 0; k < ZPIX; k++){                                                  
      fprintf(outfile, "%lf ", grid[getindex(i,j,k)]);                          
    }                                                                           
    fprintf(outfile,"\n");                                                      
  }                                                                             
}                                                                               
fprintf(stderr,"Finished Writing to outfile\n");                                
#endif
```

After running the grid data list through this routine, I have `XPIX*YPIX` lines in the lookup_table, each with `ZPIX` entries. Is this an incorrect format? VisIt continues to fail reading the input file. I'm aware of the fact that `structured_points` may use column major indexing, but my first goal of course is to get some sort of result from VisIt. I would like to draw a contour using the scalar cell_density eventually. Is my data set simply too large?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the accepted answer to the question [vtk data format error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380780/vtk-data-format-error)? The question is debugging a VTK writer in C++ but it is very similar to your code (and of course should yield the same results).

The key point from the accepted answer is that data is written in **column major** order, *not* row major order (you seem to hint at this in your question: "I'm aware of the fact that structured_points may use column major indexing").

Also, it is always helpful (if you can) to compare your code with something which you know works. For example, VisIt provides a small C library for writing legacy VTK file formats called [VisItWriterLib](http://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=VisItWriterLib). Compare the output from your code and the VisItWriterLib to see where your data files differ. I would recommend using VisItWriterLib for your VTK IO rather than writing your own routines - no need to reinvent the wheel.

**Edit**: To answer a couple of your other questions:

> After running the grid data list through this routine, I have
>   XPIX*YPIX lines in the lookup_table, each with ZPIX entries. Is this
>   an incorrect format?

This is **not** the correct format. `LOOKUP_TABLE` should be a list of `XPIX*YPIX*ZPIX` lines, with one element per line (or alternatively, VisIt will accept one line with `XPIX*YPIX*ZPIX` elements). See the section *Dataset Attribute Format* in the VTK File Formats document (www.vtk.org/VTK/img/file-formats.pdf).

> Is my data set simply too large?

I doubt it. VisIt is designed to handle *huge* datasets and, AFAIK, can render petabyte data sets. I would be very surprised if your data is that large.

However, if you are concerned about having large files, you can split your data into multiple files and tell VisIt to read these files is parallel. To do this, write a bit a your data into separate files, e.g. `domain1.vtk`, `domain2.vtk`, ... `domainN.vtk` etc. Then write a `.visit` master file, which has the structure

```
!NBLOCKS N
domain1.vtk
domain2.vtk
...
domainN.vtk
```

Save this as, for example, `mydata.visit` and then open this `.visit` file, rather than the `.vtk` files, in VisIt.

Comment: Thank you for the first reply. I have now changed my input format so that the DEFAULT LOOKUP_TABLE lists one entry per line.

After reoformatting the vtk file and trying to get a contour, I get the following error message:

    engine_ser(1582) malloc: *** mmap(size=1549684736) failed (errorcode=12)
    *** error: can't allocate region
    *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug 
    couldn't be computed on local host...
Which, leads me to believe that my dataset may in fact be too large.

Comment: @user1139057 How large is your data? What are the typical values of `XPIX`, `YPIX` and `ZPIX`? When you say you get an error, do you mean when you try to open your file in VisIt? Try running VisIt with a higher level of debuging (for example start VisIt with a command like `/path_to_visit/visit/ -debug 5`. See [this FAQ](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/visit/FAQ.html#4) for a bit more information.

Comment: The typical values of XPIX, YPIX and ZPIX are 500, each of type double. This means that I'm trying to allocate approx 1.4GB of memory. (My macbook has only 2GB). I am currently running VisIt in debug mode, hopefully the debug files will reveal some new information

Comment: After running in debug -5 mode, visit continues to give the following error messages:
--GUI--
engine_ser(1582) malloc: *** mmap(size=1549684736) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
 couldn't be computed on local host
--Debug_Log File---
Exception: (LostConnectionException) /Users/whitlock2/Development/2.3RC_trunk/src/common/comm/SocketConnection.C, line 169: <The reason for the exception was not described>
catch(LostConnectionException) Users/whitlock2/Development/2.3RC_trunk/src/viewer/main/ViewerEngineManager.C:1895

Comment: @user1139057 The size of your data should not be a problem, VisIt rarely, if ever, reads an entire file into memory all at once. I suggest that you compare your VTK file to that written by using VisItWriterLib. If they are identical then your file format is fine and you have a separate issue.

Comment: @user1139057 If comparing your data file to VisItWriterLib doesn't solve the problem I suggest subscribing to the VisIt users [mailing list](https://elist.ornl.gov/mailman/listinfo/visit-users) and asking your question there. The VisIt guys are always very helpful and will be more able to get to the bottom of this problem than me.